# AJAX Call to JSON File Fails to Show Data in Treeview Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I have tried much to do this but failed, I want to show data which is in the JSON file to be loaded via the ajax call and using the TreeView JS plugin I want to show it in a TreeView but I don't know where I'm wrong. Here is what I tried.

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title> test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" />

  <style>
  </style>
  <script> // JS Code
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "./js/response.json",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data)
     {
    $('#treeview').treeview({data:data});
     }
   });

  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <div id="treeview"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JSON file contents:

```
{
    "files": {
        "cookies_policy": "",
         "eMxdhb7i": "",
         "pro": "",
         "trends": "",
         "api": "",
         "/": "",
         "FfGKmKD5": "",
         "tools": "",
         "archive": "",
         "privacy": "",
         "alerts": "",
         "9Fq13m5b": "",
         "languages": "",
         "2YX95ccy": "",
         "RxcrFUVZ": "",
         "dmca": "",
         "signup": "",
         "faq": "",
         "85zyx0mp": "",
         "settings": "",
         "scraping": "",
         "messages": "",
         "DCWujcGi": "",
         "contact": "",
         "FZTPHnt9": "",
         "login": ""
    },
     "folders": {
        "services": {
            "files": {
                "dedicated-servers.php": ""
            },
             "folders": {

            },
             "list_files": [
                "dedicated-servers.php"
            ],
             "list_folders": [

            ]
        }
    },
     "list_files": [
        "trends",
         "api",
         "tools",
         "faq",
         "login",
         "messages",
         "alerts",
         "settings",
         "archive",
         "DCWujcGi",
         "9Fq13m5b",
         "FfGKmKD5",
         "2YX95ccy",
         "85zyx0mp",
         "FZTPHnt9",
         "eMxdhb7i",
         "RxcrFUVZ",
         "pro",
         "signup",
         "/",
         "languages",
         "privacy",
         "cookies_policy",
         "contact",
         "dmca",
         "scraping"
    ],
     "list_folders": [
        "services"
    ]
}
```

But i tried all possible ways i found on the internet but couldn't find any way , can some one help me out with this struggle? All i see is a blank page.
I don't know where im wrong here. I need guidance on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use retrieved data and get in treeview option like this:

```
$('#treeview').treeview({
  data: myData
});
```

Mayby your data is here, i can not try your script:

```
success: function(myData) ...
```